# Materialize a CTE, or otherwise increase performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, parent-child, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Given a table (AccountId, ParentId NULL), we want to be able to quickly find:
1. The master parent ID (the accountId where ParentId is null).
2. All children for a given account ID.

With a CTE this is fairly easy. However, we can't save the CTE in an indexed view, which hurts performance. We've kicked around some other ideas, like saving the path (id1/id2/id3) in another field, but that feels sorta hacky.

We thought of a trigger that'd save the "master" ID on each row, but we're unsure how that'd work in the middle of a chain (1 owns 2 owns 3, but then 2 transfers to 7). It also doesn't solve the "find all children" query.

Any thoughts? We're using SQL 2008 R2, but can move to SQL 2012.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server 2012 has any functionality that will help here. However it's very tough without more context to understand why materializing the CTE or creating an indexed view (of what?) will be the magic answer to your performance problems. Can you give us some idea of the table structure, indexes, amount of data, and the queries you're running that are too slow?

Comment: Do you have index coverage for ParentId?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL 2008, there is a hierarchyid type that basically implements the saving the path to the root.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

If your hierarchy is mostly static, nother option is to have a de-normalized version of this table with the combination of a parent to every descendant.  So if your hierarchy is A is a parent of B who is a parent of C, the denormalized table can look like this

```
parent child depth
A      A     0
A      B     1
A      C     2
B      B     0
B      C     1
C      C     0
```

Now if you index both the parent and the child columns, searching the hierarchy becomes very fast.